# git mergetool throws an error "mv: cannot move <file> to <file_backup_3056>: function not implemented

Tags: windows, git, git-bash, meld

I'm trying to setup Meld as my difftool as this is something I've used for a few years now and what I'm comfortable with.

As usual, I setup my meld on my `PATH` and put

```
[merge]
    tool = meld
[diff]
    guitool = meld
```

in my global config.

Now, when I do `git mergetool` upon conflicts, I get this strange error:

[image]

And my meld is opening up like this:
[image]

I've tried several variations of the difftool command like:

```
    [mergetool "meld"]
         cmd = meld.exe "$LOCAL" "$MERGED" "$REMOTE" --output "$MERGED"
         cmd = meld "$LOCAL" "$BASE" "$REMOTE" --output "$MERGED"
```

(one of those at a time) and, while local works, base and remote doesn't work. Executing `git mergetool` produces these files in my local dir:

[image]

Which is in line with the first error - cannot mv or cp to things... how do I fix this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These "function not implemented" errors indicate that you're working in a file system that does not support the normal POSIX semantics that Git relies on.  It's not clear precisely *why* you are getting these errors.  [Sometimes Docker goes crazy](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/5955), some people report various issues with WSL, some versions of SMB/Samba will sometimes do this, and so on.  (I mention WSL specifically because of your [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) and [git-bash](/questions/tagged/git-bash) tags.)

Once you're in this state, nothing in *Git* can fix it.  If it's a Docker issue, restarting Docker may clear it up.

If you're working in a cloud-synced folder, don't do that: work in a local folder.  Git *needs* the POSIX semantics, especially within the `.git` repository proper, and cloud-synced systems don't respect this.

Comment: Thank you... will try to figure this out!